# DHCP to real network from VMWare machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2003, vmware, dhcp

I'm currently working on a project involved in deploying Windows 7 (configured to our needs) to a lot of netbooks. For that I'm planning to use Acronis Snap Deploy and to push images through ethernet. I'm currently having issues with DHCP service though, because I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate on my PC (main). I tried to use programs which run DHCP services, but they all failed for some reason.

The thing is complicated with the fact, that my PC belongs to our corporate network with our our Domain and DHCP server - I connect to the network through WiFi.

I plan to use PCs Ethernet to create my own "private netbook network" :) I have to turn off my Wireless so that my PCs DHCP won't conflict with corporate's.

So my questions are:

1) If issue IS REALLY in DHCP programs, would I able to run Windows 2003 Server from Vmware Workstation, so that it would issue IP Addresses to the netbooks?

2) If you know better ways of deploying images to multiple PCs, can you advice me on that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What network will netbooks be plugged in? You are talking about "private netbook network". Does it mean that all the netbooks are plugged in a network with only your PC and netbooks?

If so, you should install a DHCP server on your PC and enjoy. Netbooks get IP from your PC, no one knows about corporate network.

Comment: yep, there's only my PC and netbooks. everything is connected via hub. 

So you eman fact that my PC belongs to corporate domain shouldn't be problem when issuing IPs through DHCP? Should i try to use DHCP programs then?

Comment: I mean that you can do it in autonomous manner. Disconnect your PC from corporate domain. Install a DHCP server on your PC. It will give netbooks proper IP addresses, then do whatever you want with them.

Answer (score 0):

DHCP works by using broadcast. If your computer is connected to a corporate network that already uses DHCP, your new DHCP server may answer requests from other corporate PCs. You don't want that.

You need to make sure your DHCP server doesn't have a way to talk to the corporate network. You could put another network interface (like wifi you mentioned) in the PC, then make sure the DHCP server only hands out addresses on that non-corporate interface.

Using virtualization won't help unless the DHCP clients (the netbooks) are also virtual machines.